# How to Parse Complex XML with Nested Elements and Preserve Specific Inline Elements in Text

Tags: xml-parsing

I'm working with an XML structure that includes deeply nested elements and inline elements (**`<extref>`**) within text nodes. I need to parse this XML to traverse and find paths to the leaf nodes, while also preserving the position and structure of **`<extref>`** elements within the text.

Example XML snippet:

```
<document>
    <section id="1" title="Introduction">
        <paragraph>
            Introduction text with an <extref doc="jci1.3:c:BWBR0010480&amp;artikel=1" label-id="1081104">external reference</extref> embedded within the paragraph.
        </paragraph>
    </section>
    <section id="2" title="Main Content">
        <paragraph>
            Main content with another <extref doc="jci1.3:c:BWBR0010481&amp;artikel=2" label-id="1081105">external reference</extref> included in the text.
        </paragraph>
    </section>
</document>
```

The challenge is twofold:

1. Efficiently traversing the XML to access leaf nodes. leadnode could be conditional (eg last node that has a certain element).
2. Keeping the **`<extref>`** elements intact within the text nodes, including their attributes and relative position in the text.

I've tried a couple of parsers and fast-xml-parser seems the most promising but I'm facing issues whichever options I choose: either the reference texts do not remain inline or the order of the nested elements is is not preserverd.

Could anyone suggest a parsing strategy or a library in NodeJS that can handle this complexity effectively?

I tried xml2js and fast-xml-parser with muliple options